# Programatically populate custom list column

Tags: 2010, list, event-receivers, column, calculated-column

I have a list definition project (`schema.xml`, etc.). I would like to create a computed column that's available for grouping, but not have the computed value from a CAML query, as it's going to be relatively complex and needs some C#.

Can an `SPListEventReceiver` or `SPItemEventReceiver` give me a hook to provide a computed value for a column based on other values in the same row? How?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should not look at it as a "Computed column" to avoid further confusion, but rather as a Read-Only column (use `ShowInNewForm`, `ShowInEditForm` with `FALSE` in your list schema) and complement this with an `OnItemUpdated` list item event handler to update the value programatically - examples  - programatically - http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/05/how-to-hide-column-of-sharepoint-list.html or declaratively (http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2008/07/07/how-to-customize-rendering-of-sharepoint-list-form-fields-part-1.aspx)

Is as simple as that - examples of updating fields through event handlers are all over the web. I would recommend Karin's series for tips http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-theory/

Some tips:

- You could attach your event handler directly from within your List
  definition, but rather create your own content type, which is bound
  to the list - this way everywhere you use that Content type - the
  Event handler gets activated
- Use "Synchronous" in the even declaration to avoid strange behaviors during updates
- Keep the code logic in the Event handler to the minimum - do not use thread.sleep, etc.
- Evaluate whether your code needs to run using elevated code (`RunAsPriviledgedUser`) - also this would impact the way you retrieve references to your column (as you might know in event handlers you would use the passed-on Properties to retrieve `SPWeb`, `SPList`, etc. - rather than getting a new reference, etc.)
- Do not forget to use the `Disable` event firing to avoid infinity update loops  http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/
- and more...maybe

Comment: Does `public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)` get fired when the list is displayed, or only when the list is modified?

Comment: more coreclty when SPListItem is updated, not the actual SPList.

Comment: That's not really what I want. I want this method to fire whenever the information is "pulled" from the item.